# I extended but still "Warning: React component classes must extend React.Component"

Tags: reactjs

Page loads as it should, but I'm getting a "React component classes must extend React.Component" warning even though I thought I extended my components.

```js
class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<h1> BooYah! </h1>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Content/> , document.getElementById("react-root")
);
```

```html
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: What is the rest of your stack? What are you using to render your jsx?

Comment: Can you give a bigger overview on code ?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.  Works fine on 0.13.3 but if I upgrade to 0.14.2 I get this error, except nothing renders.